# Extract string element from single-item HashSet

Tags: java

I have a set of strings: `HashSet<String> idSet`. If there is only one element in the set, I want to extract the string. This is what I am doing:

```
if(idSet.size() == 1) {
    String id = (String) idSet.toArray()[0];
}
```

Is this the right way to get the string if only one element is present? I wanted to check whether there is a more elegant way.

Comment: No, this is terrible. Use `idSet.iterator().next()`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider. You should write up an answer explaining why.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to convert the entire set to an array just to get one element from it. Instead, I'd use its iterator:

```
if (idSet.size() == 1) {
    String id = idSet.iterator().next();
}
```

Comment: This is much more elegant (so +1), but now you're creating an iterator object. Is that really much less wasteful than making a one-element array?

Comment: @MadPhysicist it's more the explicit cast that's the issue with that approach. What if the set is a `Set<Integer>` - you'd still be able to write `String id = (String) idSet.toArray()[0];`, only it would fail at runtime.

Comment: @AndyTurner. In that case, it may be more efficient to use `idSet.toArray(buf)[0]`, where `buf` is a 1-element `String[]` pre-allocated for the purpose.

Comment: @MadPhysicist and what about the thread safety implications of that?

Comment: @AndyTurner. What about them? Have a separate array per-thread or synchronize the extraction to make it atomic. Perhaps OP is not using multithreading at all? The fact that you have to be careful with threads is a given. Just because you *can* be an idiot and break something, doesn't mean that you should.

Comment: Oh, yikes, now we've changed 1 line of code into lots. There is not necessarily an object created by the JVM by using an iterator. Escape analysis can detect that the `Iterator` doesn't escape the block. And just because you *can* make code more complicated than necessary, doesn't mean you should: don't nano-optimize code in the name of expected performance benefits. Plus, the type safety issue.